# GoLang change the value of a config item with viper

Tags: go, config

I have a yaml config file which has all the settings for my program.
For example:

```
something:
    enabled: true
```

I am using https://github.com/spf13/viper to get the value of an item:

```
viper.GetBool("something.enabled")
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to directly change the value of "something.enabled" to "false" using viper? The changes will apply on the config file as well so it will become:

```
something:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: Do you mean: When you change your config file the configuration inside your programm gets updated, too? If yes you need to watch your config file for example with `fsnotify`. When the file is changed you use the event to reload the configuration.

Comment: @apxp Not exactly, I meant the program updates the value of an item in the config file. The opposite of what you said.

Comment: In that case I would recomend to read and marshal the config file by usind the yaml package. Then you can write into the conf file.

Comment: @apxp Ah yes, great idea! I'll try that now.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can just use the Set method, like this:

viper.Set("something.enabled", false)

Comment: it works, but notice that if you have used `viper.NewWithOptions` to set a new value for delimiter e.i. `viper.KeyDelimiter`  you should use your key delimiter instead the point e.i. the default delimiter. For example if my key delimiter is `::` the syntax should be viper.Set("something::enabled", false)